# Mail configuration in Drupal CMS site without having admin panel

Tags: drupal

I have one CMS site in Drupal 7 , there is one contact us form where we need to configure Email, but we don't have admin panel.

I found below code in contact us php file , i think this is for sending mail : 
 mail($to,$subject,$formcontent,$headers)

Can anyone guide me how to configure SMTP server's detail to drupal site without having admin panel.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Which *contact us php file* are you talking about ? SMTP server's settings are stored in database, and since you have no access to administration pages, it's likely that you won't be able to update the db.

Answer (score 0):

There's a contributed module for this purpose.
https://www.drupal.org/project/smtp - you can install this module and just from the backend user interface of Drupal, you're able to use an arbitrary SMTP server to send emails.

Also condider using https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21mail.inc/function/drupal_mail/7.x for sending emails instead of `mail`.

Comment: In this answer, I assumed that "Admin panel" is the admin panel of the hosting platform, not the admin panel of Drupal.